# Bind Dto with model and just return one Dto

Tags: c#, linq

First of all look at my code: this is `ConceptDto`:

```
public Guid ConceptId { get; set; }
public string ConceptName { get; set; }
public string ConceptLatinName { get; set; }
public List<ConceptSubDto> ConceptSubSidiary { get; set;}
```

This is the `ConceptSubDto`:

```
   public Guid ConceptSubId { get; set; }
   public string  ConceptSubName { get; set; }
```

and I have domains like that.

Now this is my application layer that have logic I want to get these by id and return just one `ConceptDto` but I don't have any idea have to map these dtos with domain models:

```
 public async Task<ConceptManagementDto> GetConceptById(Guid id)
 {
     var concept = await _conceptManagementRepository.Query()
                              .Include(x => x.conceptSubSidiaries)
                              .GetOneAsync(x => x.Id == id);
     return new ConceptManagementDto
            {
                ConceptManagementId = concept.Id,
                ConceptName = concept.ConceptName,
                ConceptLatinName = concept.ConceptLatinName,
                ConceptSubSidiary = ??
            };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should effective if your DTO has less fields:

```cs
public async Task<ConceptManagementDto> GetConceptById(Guid id)
{
     return await _conceptManagementRepository.Query()
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .Select(x = new ConceptManagementDto
        {
            ConceptManagementId = x.Id,
            ConceptName = x.ConceptName,
            ConceptLatinName = x.ConceptLatinName,
            ConceptSubSidiary = x.ConceptSubSidiaries
                .Select(sub => new ConceptSubDto
                {
                    ConceptSubId = sub.ConceptSubId,
                    ConceptSubName = sub.ConceptSubName
                })
                .ToList()
        }).First();
}
```